# Multiple primary keys in table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, innodb

A friend of mine just sent me an image of his new api database design.

When I saw it, I noticed that his user table had three primary ids.

I actually thought this wouldn't be possible.

It got me thinking... Is it okay to do this? As long as each column is unique?

I can't seem to find a reason not to do this, except the id is not primary if there are more than one.

Is this a bad database design? And why?

Comment: you can have only one primary key but this prmary key could be made by one, two, three, .... columns.

for a shopping website, the bag table have a primary key with 3 columns (maybe more).
(ID of buyers, ID of product, Amount of product)

Example : you add 2 Iphone at your bag... but after thinking, you decided that you want 3 or more.
if you forgot to add Amount, you must pass 3 differents orders because the id of the iphone is the same and you can't have same id in different rows, that why we added Amout.
When you add an other Iphone at your bag, just increase this value...

Comment: You wouldn't use a primary key for that. Thats a foreign. And i seriously hope you dont make the amount of an order column as a primary key

Comment: I just give you an example...
Is just to say that : a Primary key can be like (column1, column2, column3) where column1, column2, column3 are 3 different columns in your table

but you're right, i've done an error, we musn't add amount as primary, just id_buyer ans id_product...

Comment: I understand what you're saying, it just seems illogical :/

Comment: "Primary key" has no role in relational theory. It was a confusion from early times kept in SQL. All that matters is candidate keys. And there can be any number. My favourite example is the periodic table of the elements. Each element has a unique name, symbol and atomic number (of protons). Three candidate keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be only one column(s) designated as the PRIMARY KEY per table and most DB's will disallow usage of multiple PRIMARY KEYS. Note that a PRIMARY KEY can span multiple columns. Use UNIQUE for other column(s) that require unique values. UNIQUE keys can also be used in foreign key relationships.

Comment: Thank you, that's the kind of answer i was looking for ^^

Comment: Glad to help. A handy tool for testing that supports many different databases and versions is called SQLFiddle.